# Can I set the Node interpreter for all run / debug configuration at once in WebStorm / PhpStorm?

Tags: configuration, phpstorm, webstorm

I use PhpStorm (though this should also apply to WebStorm) to develop node projects.

I manage my node versions via `nvm` and hence always have multiple node versions available.

In the past, I always set a specific node version for a run configuration, e.g.

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.2.0/bin/node
```

which means that once I changed my node version to e.g. v11.15.0, the file link would become invalid and I have to update it to

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node
```

[image: List of node versions]

This becomes tedious, and I can have a lot of run configs per project. Now I realized, I could set the node interpreter to "Project" via:

[image: Set to project]

and it would use the one defined in the general node settings:

[image: Project setttings for node version]

This way, if I change the node version I can just change the project setting and it would be applied for all the run configuration using the project setting.

But now I have a lot of already set run configs, and I would have to change all of them one by one.

Hence: Is there a way to set all run configs at once? (Also, at best this would also reset the node interpreters for tslint / typescript and other tools.)

Or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this manually - specific interpreters chosen in run configurations (and other Node.js-dependent configs) always override the defaults, so changing the interpreter in one place won't update others. You have to set interpreter to `Project` alias everywhere, then next time you change it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**, all configs will be auto-updated